# Confused by Tuple example in TC++PL 4th Edition

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm having trouble working out exactly how this code works.

I have a shorter version of the example here, that I think qualifies for fair use:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Nil{};

// Primary template.
template<typename T1=Nil, typename T2=Nil>
struct Tuple : Tuple<T2> {
    T1 x;

    using Base = Tuple<T2>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this); }

    Tuple(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) : Base{t2}, x{t1} { }
};

// Specialization.
template<>
struct Tuple<> { Tuple() {} };

// Specialization.
template<typename T1>
struct Tuple<T1> : Tuple<> {
    T1 x;

    using Base = Tuple<>;
    Base* base() { return static_cast<Base*>(this); }
    const Base* base() const { return static_cast<const Base*>(this); }

    Tuple(const T1& t1) : Base{}, x{t1} { }
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void print_elements(ostream& os, const Tuple<T1,T2>& t)
{
    os << t.x << ", ";
    print_elements(os,*t.base());
}

template<typename T1>
void print_elements(ostream& os, const Tuple<T1>& t)
{
    os << t.x;
}

template<>
void print_elements(ostream& os, const Tuple<>& t)
{
    os << " ";
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Tuple<T1,T2>& t)
{
    os << "T1: " << typeid(T1).name() << ", T2: " << typeid(T2).name() << "\n";
    os << "{ ";
    print_elements(os,t);
    os << " }";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    cout << Tuple<double, int>{1.1, 22} << "\n";
    cout << Tuple<double>{1.1} << "\n";
    cout << Tuple<>{} << "\n";
}
```

The output of this program is (from stacked-crooked)

```
T1: d, T2: i
{ 1.1, 22 }
T1: d, T2: 3Nil
{ 1.1 }
T1: 3Nil, T2: 3Nil
{   }
```

There is only one definition of operator<< (for the primary template).

This can be called for Tuple<> and Tuple.  The way I understand this is that it really means you call operator<< for Tuple and Tuple.

Secondly, when invoked for a Tuple with defaulted (Nil) types, it calls the correct print_elements.  Why does it not call the print_elements that will output Nil values?

I added an operator<< to for Nil and that doesn't change the behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how works `print_elements`.
There is overload for `Tuple` of two elements, for `Tuple` with one element (second is Nil) and overload for `Tuple` with zero elements (both are Nil).

In `operator <<`:

when `t` is `Tuple<T1, T2>`, then `print_elements<Tuple<T1, T2> >` will be called;

when `t` is `Tuple<T1>` (really `Tuple<T1, Nil>`), then `print_elements<Tuple<T1> >` will be called, since this version is better, than `print_elements<Tuple<T1, T2> >`, where `T2` is `Nil`;

when `t` is `Tuple<>` (really `Tuple<Nil, Nil>`), then `print_elements<Tuple<> >` will be called, since this version is better, than another versions.